# IS-IS Passive Interfaces

Tags: ip, routing, protocol

I've got a question about IS-IS.
I don't really get the point of passive interfaces in IS-IS. I know passive interfaces provide a method of advertising network prefixes into IS-IS. But I don't really get the point why this is necessary. Is it for the loopback?

Thx for your help in advance.

Kind regards

Beni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from my professor:

Configuring passive interfaces is a best practice to use on all the interfaces where no protocol neighborships are expected. That applies to loopback interfaces but also to interfaces where endhosts are connected.

Hope this can help someone sometime too.

.Beni